# Semantic MediaWiki require onoi/callback-container, but it can't be installed

Tags: mediawiki, composer

I try to install the latest release of SemanticMediaWiki. When I run `composer update`, it returns the following:

```
> ComposerHookHandler::onPreUpdate
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - mediawiki/semantic-media-wiki 2.4.x-dev requires onoi/callback-container ~1.0 -> satisfiable by onoi/callback-container[1.0.0, 1.1.0] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
    - mediawiki/semantic-media-wiki 2.4.6 requires onoi/callback-container ~1.0 -> satisfiable by onoi/callback-container[1.0.0, 1.1.0] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
    - mediawiki/semantic-media-wiki 2.4.5 requires onoi/callback-container ~1.0 -> satisfiable by onoi/callback-container[1.0.0, 1.1.0] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
    - mediawiki/semantic-media-wiki 2.4.4 requires onoi/callback-container ~1.0 -> satisfiable by onoi/callback-container[1.0.0, 1.1.0] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
    - mediawiki/semantic-media-wiki 2.4.3 requires onoi/callback-container ~1.0 -> satisfiable by onoi/callback-container[1.0.0, 1.1.0] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
    - mediawiki/semantic-media-wiki 2.4.2 requires onoi/callback-container ~1.0 -> satisfiable by onoi/callback-container[1.0.0, 1.1.0] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
    - mediawiki/semantic-media-wiki 2.4.1 requires onoi/callback-container ~1.0 -> satisfiable by onoi/callback-container[1.0.0, 1.1.0] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
    - Installation request for mediawiki/semantic-media-wiki ~2.4.1 -> satisfiable by mediawiki/semantic-media-wiki[2.4.1, 2.4.2, 2.4.3, 2.4.4, 2.4.5, 2.4.6, 2.4.x-dev].
```

I have even set `minimum-stability` to `dev` and even `prefer-stable` to `false`. Nothing resolves.

It is not the first problem with Composer. It returned an error due to no set `version` in package `mediawiki/core`, which was required still by this SMW. But not at this time, surprise.

And Composer don't see the package in `composer show onoi/callback-container`. There is stable version 2.0 at all.

Answer (score 0):

Double check your `composer.json` and how you're requiring the version, this file worked for me:

```
{
  "require-dev": {
    "mediawiki/semantic-media-wiki": "~2.4.1"
  }
}
```

which is equivalent to `composer require mediawiki/semantic-media-wiki:~2.4.1` command.

If `composer show` doesn't see the right package, try the following commands:

- `composer clean` to clear the caches.
- `composer diagnose` to check for common errors.